# Let $S$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ of finite Lebesgue measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I have to show that there is a $r \in \Bbb R$ such that the Lebesgue measure $m(S \cap (-\infty, r))=1/2 \cdot m(S)$.

I've thought in some particular cases:
Since $\Bbb Q$ has measure zero, any $r$ works. For an interval, $r$ is the middle point. If it's a set of the form $I \cup N$ where $I$ is an interval and $N$ is a countable set, $r$ will be the middle point of $I$ because $N$ has measure zero.

But I'm still trying to handle the case of a disjoint union of open intervals. Maybe with that, I will be able to generalize.

Any hints or ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: What can you say about the function $r \mapsto m(S \cap (-\infty, r))$. What are its limits for $r \to \pm \infty$. Is it continuous?

Comment: @SuperTroll You can. If you do not know how to do this rigorously, you can argue as follows: If $m(S) = 0$, every $r$ will do. Otherwise, choose $r_1$, $r_2$ with $f(r_1) < \frac 12 m(S) < f(r_2)$. Why is this possible? Then you the intermediate value theorem on $[r_1, r_2]$.